# Delete worksheet if exists code

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some VBA code to see if a sheet exists and if it does deletes it and then resumes another module of code. For some reason the code I have below does not do anything and I can't figure out why.

```
Sub delete()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If worksheetexists("Export Worksheet") Then
        Set ws = Worksheets("Export Worksheet")        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False        
        ws.delete        
        Call GetData        
    Else
        Call GetData
    End If

End Sub

Public Function worksheetexists(sheetname As String, Optional wrkbk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet

    If wrkbk Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkbk = ActiveWorkbook        
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wrksht = wrkbk.Worksheets(sheetname)
    worksheetexists = (Err.Number = 0)
    Set wrksht = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: The code look syntactically correct. Are you sure the activeworkbook contains a sheet named "Export Worksheet"

Comment: Yes its there thats why I'm so confused... I'm wondering if I have the code in the wrong location. What I want to happen is run this off a push of a button before some other code is ran.

Comment: I guess we should narrow down the problem. We can check first if `worksheetexists` returns true or false. Maybe you can include a `MsgBox` in the `If` statement in the `delete()` procedure. If `worksheetexists` is true, have the `MsgBox` display True, otherwise, have it display false. That way, we can determine if that failure occurs in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code slightly:

```
Sub delete()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If worksheetexists("Export Worksheet") Then
        Set ws = Worksheets("Export Worksheet")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.delete
        Call GetData("pass")
    Else
        Call GetData("fail")
    End If

End Sub
```

and used this for `GetData()`:

```
Sub GetData(s)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

and it worked perfectly for both the *pass* and *fail* cases.  Check the spelling of the worksheet name............................**especially the number of spaces.**

Comment: Where did you put the code in its own module or in the workbook?

Comment: @BriannaCates I put all the code into a standard module.

Comment: Ok that's where I have mine too I have no idea why its not working

Answer (score 0):

@BriannaCates, the function bellow works for me, maybe works for you.

```
Public Function deleteWorksheet(sheet As String, Optional work As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim deleted As Boolean

    If work Is Nothing Then
        Set work = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    deleted = False
    For Each ws In work.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheet Then
            ws.Delete
            deleted = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    deleteWorksheet = deleted

End Function
```